# How to check number of rows consistency in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, consistency

I have a database for saving various forms. I have a table of forms:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_formtype;

CREATE TABLE formtype (
    id_ft integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('seq_formtype'),
    name text
);
```

I have a table of different input fields in the form:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_formstruct;

CREATE TABLE formstruct (
    id_fs integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('seq_formstruct'),
    id_ft integer NOT NULL,
    name text,
    id_fstype text NOT NULL
);
```

And finally, I have a table in which I store the results from the form for each trial.

```
CREATE TABLE results (
    id_trial integer NOT NULL,
    id_fs integer NOT NULL,
    res_value text
);
```

When I add the result, I want to check whether all inputs from formstruct were inserted - that means that there will be for each entry in `formstruct where formtype = typ_trialu` (pseudocode) an entry in results.

Now I am not even sure how to check it or where to start. My idea was to create a trigger that would check the consistency after insertion to results (ie after insertion of all inputfield results).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done with trigger(s) after insert statements.

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_form_types_trigger
    AFTER INSERT ON results
    FOR EACH STATEMENT
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_form_types_function();
```

And, in `check_form_types_function` (which should be [plpgsql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql.html)) you can [raise an exception](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) if your data (as a whole) are not consistent.

But, in the other hand, if you do this, you literally won't be able to insert partial data into `results`; you will be able to insert only whole data, with a **single** insert statement. And if you *really* care about consistency, you should do this check after each update & delete statements too.

**Notes**:

- names like `fs`, `ft`, `fstype` are terrible, consider rename your columns.
- consider using [`SERIAL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)s (instead of just manually set up sequences)
- consider using [foreign keys](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-fk.html)

Comment: Actually, the code above uses Foreign keys,I just wanted to show the shortes code, but thank you for the hint. Also, for some reason I have to decide not to use serial datatype but I do not remember why so I will give it another look because now I cannot find the problem with serial datatype. Anyway, I have thought that SERIAL type is the same as using SEQUENCES, isn't it? (Offtopic - Good answer and I appreciate the note section)

Comment: @Pter almost the same, but sequences also have an ownership (`OWNED BY` clause) which comes in handy, if you want to drop your tables / columns (owned sequences also drops, f.ex.) - this is automatically set up with serials (behind the scenes), and makes your code simpler, and more readable.